# Invoke-SqlCmd QueryTimeout

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell, powershell-2.0

Does anyone know how to set Invoke-SqlCmd QueryTimeout more than 65535?

Microsoft said that they have fixed it in Denali but we are still using SQL 2008 R2 with latest service packs.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/551799/invoke-sqlcmd-querytimeout-0-still-times-out

Basically, we are trying to backup or restore the database using powershell. Some of our databases are very large so it takes more than 65535 to complete the job.

Some suggested that we should use ADO.NET with timeout in powershell. But I wonder if we have any workaround for Invoke-SqlCmd...

Comment: Are you determined to use `Invoke-SqlCmd`? If you can't upgrade your client to SQL 2012, you could try working around this by falling back to executing `SQLCMD` directly using `cmd /c` or carrying out your backup/restore using SMO.

Comment: Setting the query timeout to zero should cause it to wait until the command completes no matter how long it takes.

Comment: The version of the PS module is what's important, not the version of the server. Recent versions of Windows/PowerShell allow you to `Update-Module SqlServer` and use `-QueryTimeout 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own version of Invoke-SqlCmd that directly uses the System.Data.SqlClient object and do anything that you want to with it. There are a bunch of examples of how to do this to be found, including [invoke-sqlcmd2](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7985b7ef-ed89-4dfd-b02a-433cc4e30894), which was specifically written to get around the QueryTimeout bug and is hosted on Microsoft's scripting gallery. If you don't want to deploy such a script, you can just integrate the relevant code directly into your backup script.

Alternatively, you should be able to use SMO to backup the database. IIRC, the querytimeout bug does not affect SMO.

Comment: SMO query timeout which includes backups is 10 minutes by default. If you want longer you need to set it.

Comment: Hey, 6 years later is there anything better?  MS has updated SQLPS to `$moduleName = "SqlServer" ... Import-Module $moduleName -Verbose` yet still I'm getting a time out on a 10MB dB.

Answer (score 7):

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -query 'select * from largeDb' -QueryTimeout 0
```

**-QueryTimeout 0** : will make your cmdlet from **timing out.**

AFAIK By soon, this bug will be resolved.

Comment: Doesn't work for me when adding an index from a script. Still defaults to 60 seconds

Comment: 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = N'IX_TableName_ColumnName')   
 BEGIN
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TableName_ColumnName ON [dbo].[TableName] ([ColumnName]) 
  INCLUDE ([ColumnName2],[ColumnName3])
 END
 GO
'
- That was in my SQL script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below function to customize your own *Query time out* and *session time out* limits (while defining the parameters you can give you own desired values)

```
function Invoke-SqlCommand 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param( 
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ServerInstance, 
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Database, 
    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Query, 
    [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Username, 
    [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Password, 
    [Parameter(Position=5, Mandatory=$false)] [Int32]$QueryTimeout=600, 
    [Parameter(Position=6, Mandatory=$false)] [Int32]$ConnectionTimeout=15, 
    [Parameter(Position=7, Mandatory=$false)] [ValidateScript({test-path $_})] [string]$InputFile, 
    [Parameter(Position=8, Mandatory=$false)] [ValidateSet("DataSet", "DataTable", "DataRow")] [string]$As="DataRow" 
    ) 

    if ($InputFile) 
    { 
        $filePath = $(resolve-path $InputFile).path 
        $Query =  [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filePath") 
    } 

    $conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 

    if ($Username) 
    { $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Trusted_Connection=False;Connect Timeout={4}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$Username,$Password,$ConnectionTimeout } 
    else 
    { $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$ConnectionTimeout } 

    $conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString 

    #Following EventHandler is used for PRINT and RAISERROR T-SQL statements. Executed when -Verbose parameter specified by caller 
    if ($PSBoundParameters.Verbose) 
    { 
        $conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors=$true 
        $handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {Write-Verbose "$($_)"} 
        $conn.add_InfoMessage($handler) 
    } 

    $conn.Open() 
    $cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn) 
    $cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout 
    $ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet 
    $da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd) 
    [void]$da.fill($ds) 
    $conn.Close() 
    switch ($As) 
    { 
        'DataSet'   { Write-Output ($ds) } 
        'DataTable' { Write-Output ($ds.Tables) } 
        'DataRow'   { Write-Output ($ds.Tables[0]) } 
    } 

}
```

Hope it HElps.